# I want a javascript function to make readonly false for a textbox in a dynamic table of ascx

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, ascx

I want to add an JavaScript function through which I can make my Text Box field editable instead of it being Read Only.

Also the table is a dynamic table in which I have my Text Box.

Please help me.

Code:

```
 cell.Controls.Add(New clsHtmlInputCurr(cCTRNAMEPREFIX_ASSET_UNITPRICE, objAsset.UnitPrice, Not
                                           IsEditable(enuActEditMode.eNew, enuActEditMode.eEdit_Proc1, enuActEditMode.eEdit_Proc1_ext), "startEdit(this)", "calcAssets(this)", 15, 100, enuHtmlCtrLabel.No, intAssNo, CI).Ctrl)
```

Comment: If you have any code that you've tried already which you could show us in the question, it would give us somewhere to start an answer from.

Comment: That's easy enough.  Post some markup and any attempted code you have so far.

Comment: The code i think that is storing the value is:

Answer (score -1):

Is the textbox an asp component? If so, there's a chance that changes to values will be ignored when the page refreshes, as asp may choose to ignore the incoming value of a read only control.

Are you trying to avoid a page load? You could wrap the textbox in an UpdatePanel, then it can still be 'under asp control' while being able to change without a whole page load.

Comment: No it is an Vb component

Comment: cell.Controls.Add(New clsHtmlInputCurr(cCTRNAMEPREFIX_ASSET_UNITPRICE, objAsset.UnitPrice, Not
                                               IsEditable(enuActEditMode.eNew, enuActEditMode.eEdit_Proc1, enuActEditMode.eEdit_Proc1_ext), "startEdit(this)", "calcAssets(this)", 15, 100, enuHtmlCtrLabel.No, intAssNo, CI).Ctrl)